# URL Encode problem with chine language

Tags: javascript, forms

I have such text in chines: "回家" - seems it is "house" in english.

I go to google.com, post "回家" in search and get such url:

**http://www.google.ru/ ... q=%E5%9B%9E%E5%AE%B6**

=> q = %E5%9B%9E%E5%AE%B6

Then i go to taobao.com post "回家" to search and get url like this:
**http://search8.taobao.com/search?q=%BB%D8%BC%D2**

=> q = %BB%D8%BC%D2

Why url encoding is not the same? What encoding used on taobao?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The byte sequence for "回家" in the UTF-8 encoding is `E5 9B 9E E5 AE B6`, the byte sequence in the [GB 18030](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GB18030) encoding is `BB D8 BC D2`. Google uses UTF-8, Taobao uses GB 18030.